# How to connect to PostgreSQL with epgsql (Erlang)?

Tags: postgresql, erlang

I want to run a simple PostgreSQL query with Erlang and epgsql similar to [Erlang and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350272/erlang-and-postgresql). I am getting

```
** exception error: no match of right hand side value 
{error,
    {authentication,
        [{severity,'Ð\222Ð\220Ð\226Ð\235Ð\236'},
         {code,"28000"},
         {message,[208,191,208,190,208,187,209,140,208,183,208,190,208,178,208,176,209,130,208,181|...]},
         {file,"auth.c"},
         {line,302},
         {routine,"auth_failed"}]}}
```

on

```
{ok, C} = pgsql:connect("localhost", 
                        "postgres", 
                        "password", 
                        [{database, "postgres"}]).
```

My PostgreSQL instance works fine and I can add a table to my database or run simple queries. But I need to do it with epgsql. And furthermore, I can't read error message, this is what I can see:

```
[208,191,208,190,208,187,209,140,208,183,208,190,208,178,208,176,209,130,208,181|...]
```

Comment: The error message tells you that instead of returning {ok,C} the connect fails and send back an authentication error. So far I cannot help you more, but you should look at the connect parameters and the authentication data. If you have the source code, maybe you can get more information by reading the file auth.c around line 302.

Comment: This is a PostgreSQL error 28000 INVALID AUTHORIZATION SPECIFICATION. Are you sure you are giving the right username?

Comment: I think that the third parameter must be username, but in tutorial the third parameter is password. So what is the second parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed egpsql, did a direct test, and confirmed that the second parameter for `connect` is the username and the third is the password:

```
{ok, C} = pgsql:connect("localhost", "username", "password", [{database, "db_name"}]).
{ok, Columns, Rows} = pgsql:squery(C, "select * from myschema.mytable").
```

Comment: I think I have no correct user in my PostgreSQL. I can work with user "postgres" with one clients, but other clients throws something like auth-error (wrong password or ?). Maybe You know how correct way to add the user?

Comment: A Postgres user account and password can be created with the [create user](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createuser.html) SQL command.  The [grant](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-grant.html) command can be used to give that account permission.  However, there are other [factors](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/client-authentication.html) that can affect one's ability to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar error **28000 INVALID AUTHORIZATION SPECIFICATION**, while using **epgsql:connect** function.

I have followed the folks suggestion, changing the pg_hba.conf local method type to trust and ident. But no luck!. Tries with, by creating a new user and grant permission on the psql side as well. But no luck.

```
local   all             all                                    password #trust
```

Finally, after the following below update in the pg_hba.conf file(restart of the postgresql service), it is working for me on centos 7.

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            password #ident
```